# Launch a bash script before running my optimization model in Pycharm

Tags: python, bash, macos, pycharm, pyomo

I have Fico Xpress solver installed in my mac. I can run my optimization model from command line. Before doing so, I run `. /Applications/FICO\ Xpress/xpressmp/bin/xpvars.sh` which runs a number of commands such as `CLASSPATH=${XPRESSDIR}/lib/xprs.jar:${CLASSPATH}`, `export CLASSPATH` etc.

The issue is when I want to run the model in Pycharm. Pycharm doesn't seem to be able to find Xpress. The the 'optimizer' executable of Xpress cannot be found. In fact, I cannot even import xpress.

As a potential solution, I would like to be able to launch the xpvar.sh script before I run Pycharm.

I have been trying to use `External Tool` option in Pycharm, but get the error message `Source this script by running 'source /Applications/fico/xpressmp/bin/xpvars.sh'`

Here are the parameters I set in my `External Tool`:

**Program:** /Applications/fico/xpressmp/bin/xpvars.sh
**Arguments:** source
**Working Directory:** /Applications/fico/xpressmp/bin/

Any other potential solutions are also very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you run `source /Applications/fico/xpressmp/bin/xpvars.sh`? That seems like it should solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: In the command line you mean? If so, that does not help. Pycharm, and pyomo optimization tool that I use, still cannot find Xpress'es executable.

Comment: edit the `xpvars.sh`. If env-vars are set like `var="value"`, try changing them to `export var="value"`. Otherwise I have no idea. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that PyCharm is a GUI application and does not read the .bash_profile or .bashrc files where most environment variables are set. What worked for me is using the EnvFile plugin for PyCharm (I'm using the Community Edition 2019.2):

- Under Preferences->Plugin, search for EnvFile;
- Install the plugin, then restart PyCharm;
- Create a .env file (e.g. myvars.env) containing all variables you need, one per line, in the format VARNAME=VALUE
- Load your project, then under Run->Edit configurations, select the EnvFile tab;
- Click on the "+" to add your myvars.env;
- Maybe restart PyCharm again.

At this point your variables should be available to your Python application.